# android rating bar xml and numStars 

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm a beginner in designing with XML :D
This is the XML of my rating bar and friends :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#336699"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rtbHighScore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:max="100"
        android:rating="0.0"
        android:stepSize="0.0"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"         
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `android:numStars` is 5, but this is what i get :

[image]

I read that the `layout_width` must be `wrap_content` so the rating bar stars will follow my `android:numStars` and this is what i get when i change it to `wrap_content` :

[image]

**I want to create 5stars rating bar in the right of my textview(or the left of my right arrow image)**
Thanks :D

Comment: Any help please?really stuck here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i have an idea to use a relative layout and i also use a little drag-drop :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#336699"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rtbHighScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:max="100"
            android:rating="0.0"
            android:stepSize="0.0"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this code make my layout "perfect"

Comment: how will you use custom rating to give space between star?

Answer (score 4):

Use this Layout file for proper 5 stars.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#336699"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rtbHighScore"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:max="5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0.0"
    android:stepSize="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
```

I think  android:gravity="center_vertical"
was the problem.

Comment: Thanks :D
I tried your xml and it gives me a 5-star rating bar BUT the right blue arrow image is disappear...what should i do?can we use the layout_weight to solve this?

Comment: Or maybe you want to see my whole XML? :D